# Please clarify when a USB device resets or changes it's Data toggle

Tags: usb, data-synchronization

I'm working on a new usb device and I'm trying to understand how to track/manage the data toggle.  There is conflicting information on the web but most opinions/experiences are that the devices never change their data toggle after enumeration, with the exception of certain Setup transfers.

This seems to conflict with my reading of the specs.

Regarding bulk transfers USB2.0 spec section 8.5.2 says "The host always initializes the first transaction of a bus transfer to the DATA0 PID with a configuration event. The second transaction uses a DATA1 PID, and successive data transfers alternate for the remainder of the bulk transfer."

What I don't get here (maybe I've misunderstood it) is that there seems to be no such thing as a bulk transfer, at least nothing at this level of the protocol; there are only bulk transactions --> IN/OUT-DATA0/1-HANDSHAKE ...if so, when does the data toggle ever toggle in accordance with section 8.5.2?

Further on, in section 8.5.3 it says "A SETUP always uses a DATA0 PID for the data field of the SETUP transaction."

and further on in the same section is says "A Status stage is delineated by a change in direction of data flow from the previous stage and always uses a DATA1 PID."

Now, assuming I'm responding in a Setup transfer which begins

SETUPTOKEN|DATA0|HANDSHAKE,

then a whole bunch of transactions starting with

IN|DATA1|HANDSHAKE and ending with IN|DATA1|HANDSHAKE before the status phase.

At this point I'm expecting my data toggle to be 0 (after sending DATA1 and receivng the ACK my toggle switched from 1 to 0 in anticipation of a DATA0 in the next packet... I know, I should expect the status phase but I'm trying to show the point).

Now the Status Phase comes as per the USB 2.0 specs

OUT|DATA1| but my data toggle is 0.

but if I never interfere with the toggle, I would be stuck 'cause I'd have to ignore the DATA1 and not respond, and the host would have to resend over and over again.

So, must I intervene here by ignoring the toggle mismatch, sending the ACK, and keeping the toggle at 0 (i.e. pretend the my data toggle matched the Data1 and flipping it in anticipation of the next non-SETUP transfer/transaction?

If I follow the opinions I've read, there would be no resolution but for the device to return STALL.

Some help on this issue would be appreciated, so thanks in advance.

Edit:

Maybe I should rephrase the question - Am I misreading setion 8.5.2, do they just mean any Control transfer instead of "bus transfer"?  Can anyone confirm whether the major OSes (if any) force a Data1 transaction during the reset phase of a control transfer regardeless of which Data packet type (Data0 or Data1) was used in the immediately preceding transaction ?

Answer (score 1):

The data toggle for a Bulk Endpoint toggles for each Bulk Transaction on that Endpoint. This is shown in figure 8-35. Section 8.5.2 only refers to Bulk Transactions, not Control Transfers. The data toggle will only be reinitialised for special events.

The data toggle rules for Control Transfers are different in that the last Transaction of a Control Transfer (a Transfer is composed of several Transactions) will always have its data toggle set to 1. This is best seen in figure 8-37.

Answer (score 1):

- Data toggles are PER ENDPOINT.
- There are 32 possible endpoints, each addressed by a combination of "endpoint number" and direction (IN/OUT).
- Do not confuse the 2 terms "endpoint" and "endpoint number"!
- A Control transfer uses a pair of 2 endpoints with the same number.
- Usually control transfers are only performed on the endpoint pair with number 0.
- When a SETUP token is received on the OUT endpoint with number X, BOTH ENDPOINTS with number X will reset their data toggle to DATA0 (meaning that the next DATA packet on that endpoint must be a DATA1).
- Now read again the very first rule: Data toggles are PER ENDPOINT.
- This means that if the data stage uses a bunch of IN transactions, this only toggles the DATAx toggle of the IN endpoint with number X. The OUT endpoint stays the same, meaning it expects a DATA1, regardless of how many IN transactions happen. The same applies in the other direction. If the Data stage uses a bunch of OUT transactions, only the OUT endpoint gets toggled. Because the Data stage can only go one direction and the Status stage always goes the other direction, the Status stage always uses a DATA1 packet. There is nothing special about this. It's just a consequence of the fact that Data toggles are per endpoint, NOT PER ENDPOINT NUMBER!